# iOS modify string to have no line spaces

Tags: ios, json, string, twitter

I am pulling tweets from Twitter and using this to convert it into an array:

```
NSArray *feedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonError];
```

Some of the tweets have a large number of new lines and white space, which has become increasingly annoying for the sake of layout.

I want to turn any strings that have multiple lines into a single lined string.

Here is an example string that I need to convert:

```
I used #ECSliding  library with my project but i can’t used with
#UITableView plz provide me the way if u know it.

@kbegeman 

&amp; thank u ;
```

As you can see this mention has a bunch of white space and couple extra lines.

I have tried using this:

```
NSString *tweet = [currentTweet objectForKey:@"text"];
NSString *trimmedTweet  = [tweet stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

And I also tried this:

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingstringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];  
myString = [myString stringByReplacingstringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Does it have something to do with the way I am reading in the JSON? Am I using that method wrong? Is there any other solution anyone can think of? Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` trims chars from the start and end of the receiver.  You'll probably want something like:

```
NSString *trimmedTweet = [tweet stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
```

Comment: I swear I just tried this 20 minutes ago, but it didn't work. Then I copy pasted your code in and it worked like a charm! Not gonna complain haha, and your answer is correct! Thanks a lot!